# Como mudar a cor do background conforme a pagina rolar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

olá, futuramente vou receber um projeto em que o background terá que mudar de cor conforme o conteudo que aparecer na tela,  mas ainda não tive nenhuma experiencia com esse tipo de ação. Se alguém tiver um script especifico para ajudar ou um método pra me passar serei eternamente grato.

Comment: Uma das formas é criar alguns "pontos de ancoragem", ou seja, você vai identificando alguns elementos em pontos específicos da página e, sempre que a barra de rolagem se encontrar nesse ponto, o evento de mudança de cor é disparado para a cor em questão.

Comment: Aqui um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/7o4ebrw6/

Comment: De longe a melhor solução que vi até agora, muito obrigado! Tenho apenas duas duvidas quanto a solução: não sei se é um bug apenas comigo mas notei que ao rolar a pagina com o scroll a pagina não altera o background, apenas quando a barra de scroll em si é movida, teria algum método de consertar isso? a outra pergunta é referente as posições em que é alterado o BG; Poderia me dizer em qual linha consigo alterar se a cor vai mudar com a pagina mais pra baixo ou pra cima? Sei muito pouco de JS ainda então costumo ficar bem confuso. Novamente, agradeço muito pela ajuda.

Comment: O bug que citou não ocorre comigo, talvez seja o navegador ou a versão do navegador que você esteja utilizando, quanto a segunda pergunta, quem vai definir em qual parte a cor irá mudar será a posição na qual colocou o elemento que dispara esse evento. Veja esse novo exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/jh1rkm0f/1/. De todo modo, esse é um exemplo bem simples e que precisa de muitas melhorias. Eu o criei não como um caminho a ser seguido, mas sim, como um ponto de partida para o entendimento da questão. Mas existem formas mais robustas e até plugins jQuery que são capazes de fazer isso.

Comment: Um outro exemplo utilizando atributos "data-color": https://jsfiddle.net/p2g3av08/

Comment: @Boneman, sem palavras irmão, chegou o dia de aplicar esse background no projeto e foi extremamente tranquilo por causa da tua ajuda, só tenho a agradecer pelo apoio.